# Unable to Post to a Feed Group in GetStream

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I'm currently using Stream to build Feeds in our React Native app.

I ran into a problem enabling users to post to a new board feed group I made.

Currently iOS only

**Problem:** I have created a "board" feed group and want to allow users to post to that feed group to save posts. I have enabled permissions for this as per: https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed/issues/23 via support. Yet I am still unable to post to the "board" feed group but I'm still receiving a permissions error.

I'm using the SinglePost component from the official React Native GetStream library and have a save button on the activity component.

The save button opens a modal to allow a user to select a board and after a user selects a board the _saveBoard method is called. You can see the full method here.

```
 _saveToBoard = item => {
    let boardId = item.id;

    console.log('boardId', boardId, this.props);

    // // Add activity to selectedBoard
    var selectedBoard = this.props.client.feed('board', boardId);

    let activity_data = {
      actor: this.props.client.currentUser.id,
      verb: 'save',
      object: `BoardPost:${generateId()}`
    };

    console.log('activity data', activity_data);

    selectedBoard
      .addActivity(activity_data)
      .then(res => console.log('added activity', res))
      .catch(err => console.log('error adding activity to board', err));

    console.log('selectedBoard', selectedBoard);
  };
```

Not sure where I went wrong and hoping its something I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default permission policies don't allow a user to add an activity with actor set to anything else than current user's reference. This restriction is only enforced client-side to make sure that users are not able to impersonate other users.

Changing actor from `this.props.client.currentUser.id` into `this.props.client.currentUser.id` will make sure that the activity is added with a user reference equal to current user.